# I am loosing chat messages when i refresh the page with socketio but they are saved in DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io

I created private chat app using Socketio with nodejs server. i am saving chat messages to monogdb and sending back tom client but when i refresh page chat messages are disappearing but they are save d to db. Can anyone help me please?

**CLient**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connection established!");
    });
    socket.on("loggedin", () => {
      console.log("you're logged in!");
      setLoggedIn(true);
      fetchOnlineUsers();
      socket.on("newConnection", () => {
        console.log("watch out! a new challenger appears!");
        fetchOnlineUsers();
      });
    });

    socket.on("message", (newMessage) => {
      console.log("a new message appeared!", newMessage);
      setChatHistory((chatHistory) => [...chatHistory, newMessage]);
    });
  }, []);
```

**SERVER**

```
  socket.on("sendmessage", async({ message, room }) => {
        const newMessage = new MsgModel({ 
            text:message.text,
            sender: message.sender,
            socketId:message.socketId
        });
        newMessage.save().then(() => {
            socket.to(room).emit('message', newMessage)
        })
        console.log("Message",newMessage);
        // Emits only to people inside of the defined "room"
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shared, I can only understand that you are sending messages to the receiver through socket, but when the user connects again to that particular `room`, are you fetching all previous messages from your mongo conversation document?

In order to receive messages that were sent previously, you need to fetch all messages associated to that room when the user first loads the page. You can create another API that fetches the records from where you previously stored your messages and list it for the user like you do when receiving the `message` socket trigger